# Issue in parsing an array of string from server response

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following json string from api response...

```
    ["products": <__NSArrayI 0x7fa103868000>(
    {
        barcode = HDz;
        "category_json" = "[{\"category_name\":\"Home\",\"category_id\":\"2\"}]";
        "created_at" = "2018-04-09 12:56:35";
        "discount_price" = "5000.00";
.....
```

I'm parsing this response like so...

```
if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {

                        print("SUCCESS!")

                        if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                            print(result)

                            guard let products = result["products"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
                                return
                            }

                            for value in products {
                                if let barcode = value["barcode"] as? String {
                                    self.theBarcode = barcode
                                }

                                if let discountPrice = value["discount_price"] as? String {
                                    self.theDiscountRate = discountPrice
                                }
                                //Issue arises here
                                guard let category = value["category_json"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                                    return
                                }
```

Everything works fine. But when I reach the category part the control goes to return and an exit happens. Don't know why this is happening...

Comment: Why don't you use the `Codable` methods introduced in Swift4? Moreover, please include the raw JSON response in your question and not the console output after printing the partially parsed JSON.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure how it can be used in this scenario @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: `value["category_json"]` is a String. It's JSON Stringified inside JSON. You need to do `let categoryStringified = value["category_json"] as String let category =try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: categoryStringified.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as [[String:Any]]`

Comment: Well..I tried what u suggested @Larme. But at this part `let category = try?...` I get this error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

Comment: I coded it without compiler and autocompletion ie: pseudo code. It was missing info/params. I answered with code tested in Playground, so it should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"category_json":"[{\"category_name\":\"Home\",\"category_id\":\"2\"}]"
```

That's JSON (Stringified) within JSON.

What's your tools:
`Dictionary or Array` object <= (through) `JSONSerialization`) => `Data` object
`String` object < = > `Data` object

So you need to parse it again using `JSONSerialization()`.

```
let categoryStringified = "[{\"category_name\":\"Home\",\"category_id\":\"2\"}]"
//in your case let categoryStringified = value["category_json"] as String
let categoryStringifiedData = categoryStringified.data(using: .utf8)
let categories = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: categoryStringifiedData!, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]
print("categories: \(categories)")
for aCategory in categories {
   ...
}
```

Side note: For the sake of the logic, I forced unwrapped, didn't do a `catch` on the `try?` etc. 
You already know how to manage them (you use `guard let`, `if let`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Larme. It worked. Have given an upvote also...:) Also would you mind explaining in bit what u meant by the statements...`String object <= (through) JSONSeria...`

Comment: Fixed it: it's `Dictionary or Array` not `String`. I meant that you have way to go from Array to Data, and Data To String (and vice-versa, in a JSON way) and since you have a String JSON, you can comeback to an Array that you know how to work with.

Comment: Yes. my `categories` is your `category` (if your code would have worked). Since it's an array that could hold various categories, I named it `categories` (plural), that's all.